# How to display objects that are inside array using map method in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, null

```
const ViewCategory = () => {
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/category/list/', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("List of customers", response.data);
            setData(response.data);
            setisLoaded(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, []);

const [data, setData] = useState();
const [isloaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);

const AddSubcategory = (categoryId, categoryName) => {
    history.push('/AddSubCategory', {
        categoryId,
        categoryName
    })
}

let category = null;
if (isloaded) {
    category = data.map(category1 => ( <
        div className = "col-sm-10" >
        <
        table class = "table table-bordered" >
        <
        thead >
        <
        tr >
        <
        th > Id < /th> <
        th > Name < /th> <
        th > AddCategory < /th> <
        /tr> <
        /thead> <
        tbody >
        <
        tr >
        <
        td > {
            category1.id
        } < /td> <
        td > {
            category1.name
        } < /td> <
        td > < button className = "btn btn-primary"
        onClick = {
            () => AddSubcategory(category1.id, category1.name)
        } > Add Subcategory < /button></td >
        <
        /tr> <
        /tbody> <
        /table> <
        /div>
    ))
}

return ( <
    div > {
        category
    } < /div>
);
```

}

[image]

I am trying to display parentCategory Id using map method I tried it by displaying using category1.parentCategory.category1.id but this throws an error.The main problem is the value of electronics parentCategory is set  null because of which it throws an error "cannot read property of null".For further reference I have attached 2 screenshoots to make things clear[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate that `null` try this

```
resp.map(val=> val.parentCategory && val.parentCategory.id)
```

Comment: Where should I place this code . I am new to react can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (isloaded) {
category = <div lassName = "col-sm-10" >
    <table class = "table table-bordered" >
        <thead >
            <tr >
                <th > Id < /th> 
                <th > ParentCategory ID < /th> 
                <th > Name < /th>
                <th > AddCategory < /th> 
            < /tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody >
        {data.map(category1 =>category1.parentCategory && <tr key={category1.id} >
        <td > {category1.id} < /td>
        <td > {category1.parentCategory.id} < /td>
        <td > {category1.name} < /td> 
        <td > < button className = "btn btn-primary" 
            onClick = {() => AddSubcategory(category1.id, category1.name)}> Add Subcategory < /button>
        </td >
        </tr> }
        </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

}